# How to change the output size of the variational autoencoder in Matlab

Tags: matlab, autoencoder

The Variational Autoencoder (VAE), which is included in the Matlab deep learning toolbox, takes its input from the MNIST dataset by default. It actually takes the 28 * 28 images from the inputs and regenerates outputs of the same size using its decoder.
I want to use this network on my own data which are 128 * 128 RGB images. However, the decoder regenerates outputs of size 28 * 28 images.
How can I set the decoder to regenerates the images with the same size as the input?
Here is a part of the code that I am using:

```
latentDim = 50;
imageSize = [128 128 3];
encoderLG = layerGraph([
    imageInputLayer(imageSize,'Name','input_encoder','Normalization','none')
    convolution2dLayer(5, 32, 'Padding','same', 'Stride', 2, 'Name', 'conv1')
    reluLayer('Name','relu1')
    convolution2dLayer(5, 64, 'Padding','same', 'Stride', 2, 'Name', 'conv2')
    reluLayer('Name','relu2')
    fullyConnectedLayer(2 * latentDim, 'Name', 'fc_encoder')
    ]);
decoderLG = layerGraph([imageInputLayer([1 1 latentDim],'Name','i','Normalization','none')
    transposedConv2dLayer(7, 64, 'Cropping', 'same', 'Stride', 7, 'Name', 'transpose1')
    reluLayer('Name','relu1')
    transposedConv2dLayer(5, 64, 'Cropping', 'same', 'Stride', 2, 'Name', 'transpose2')
    reluLayer('Name','relu2')
    transposedConv2dLayer(5, 32, 'Cropping', 'same', 'Stride', 2, 'Name', 'transpose3')
    reluLayer('Name','relu3')
    transposedConv2dLayer(5, 1, 'Cropping', 'same', 'Name', 'transpose4')
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the decoder's layers. For example with the stride sizes: The strides sizes are 7 * 2 * 2 * 1 = 28.
Hopefully someone else comes up with a more insightful response.